# Remove multiple applications from Applications view in Domino Designer

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

Over time, the list of applications builds up and reduces performance.  I know, I should remove them after I've finished, but I haven't.  I can right-click on each one individually and remove it, but that is time consuming.

Is there a way to remove multiple applications from the Applications View in Domino Designer in one go?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://ivisions.wordpress.com/2011/08/11/clean-up-project-list-from-applications-view-in-domino-designer/

Comment: Thanks Per.  That's what I did.  Much faster DDE now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can delete multiple databases from Designer's Applications view at at time:

- go to Designer's tab "Packagage Explorer",
- select databases you want to delete from workspace
- press delete button
- click OK (**don't** select "Delete project content on disk")

The corresponding databases get deleted from Applications view then too.

(You can oben tab "Packagage Explorer" at Designer's menu
"Window > Show Eclipse Views > Package Explorer")

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this (after I'd used Per's suggestion) and it works how I want.  This will be a lot easier day to day.